# What is the purpose of static_cast<int>?

Tags: c++

So I have to do some research in random numbers, I watched some tutorials and read a little bit of how to do it, and then did this code, but I didn't understand completely, so I wanted to know why does my code work and what is the purpose of static_cast.

```
#include<iostream>  
#include<cstdlib>  
#include<ctime> 
 
using namespace std;

int main(){
    srand(time (0)); 

    cout<<60+rand()%static_cast<int>(140-60+1)<<endl;

}
```

Comment: If those tutorials recommend `rand()` they are by definition not worth reading.

Comment: **WARNING**: Using [`rand()` can be highly problematic](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and you’re strongly encouraged to use an appropriate [random number generator facility in the Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that produces high-quality random values. Using `time(NULL)` as a random number will produce identical results if run in the same second, and on many platforms `rand()` is barely random at all. Use [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Comment: Your `static_cast` is converting `int` to `int`. It is not required.

Comment: @MikeCAT Just more evidence of a fundamentally, deeply flawed "tutorial".

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work" in technical terms? Do you get an error? If so, what is the *exact* error text?

Comment: As said already, your *current* `static_cast` does nothing; however, you could use one in your call to `srand`: `srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));`.

Comment: The technical purpose of `static_cast<int>(x)` is to convert `x` to an `int`.   Since `140-60+1` has type `int`, converting it to an `int` has no effect.    In this case, the use of `static_cast` is for other programmers to know that the author of this code is an amateur who adds impressive or complicated-looking constructs to make code look more significant, while not understanding the code they have written.

Comment: @tadman — if I were writing a tutorial for beginners and needed a source of randomness I would not hesitate to use `rand()’. It’s much easier to explain and to use than the new stuff, and it’s good enough for beginners, who don’t need to be further overwhelmed with that complexity. The new stuff comes later.

Comment: @PeteBecker What? No. The documentation on `std::uniform_int_distribution` has a snippet that you can use as-is, super easy, no fuss or confusion. `rand()` is confusing because it has all kinds of hidden caveats that you will only discover down the road when it's too late to fix. It's three lines of code and *actually random* compared to `srand(time(NULL))` which is, at the absolute best, random-ish so long as you don't call it twice in the same second.

Comment: @tadman -- I suggest that you redirect your contempt to `std::endl` and `using namespace std;`, which are much more common, have far worse consequences, and are much simpler to replace.

Comment: As for that snippet, for beginners it's a magic incantation, and it relies on `std::random_device`, which is often random-ish in undocumented ways. You pays yer money and you takes yer choice.

Comment: @PeteBecker What's your beef with `std::endl`? The flushing? I have one for `using namespace std` but that's going to be a long, long fight.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the purpose of `static_cast<int>`?

The purpose of static_cast is to explicitly convert a value of one type into another type. The purpose of `static_cast<int>` is to convert to the type int.

In the example, the value of already int, so the conversion is redundant and has no purpose.

> why does my code work

That's kind of a broad question. It works if it does what you intended, and has no undefined behaviour.

We don't know what you intend the program to do, but I can tell that its behaviour is well defined.

---

P.S. `rand` produces poor quality randomness. Its usage is not recommended when that quality is needed. The `<random>` header is a better option in such case.

P.P.S Avoid `using namespace std`.

Comment: Re: “`rand` produces poor quality randomness“ — there’s no such requirement. The one I wrote for Dinkumware is quite good.

Comment: Probably fairer to say that the standard doesn't specify much about the quality (e.g the randomness of values) of `rand()` and that quite a few implementations (compilers and their associated standard library) provide a rather poor quality `rand()`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Sure. But "`rand` bad" is simpler and easier for beginners to understand and gets the important parts of the correct message across (and it is the correct message because there are stdlib implementations where `rand` isn't good). Out of curiosity, which algorithm did you choose?

Comment: The “correct message” should not be “do this much more complex stuff, because if you use the simple stuff now you’ll just have to learn the more complex stuff later”. Beginners are overwhelmed by details, and don’t need additional complexity. For the programs that beginners write, `rand()` is good enough. More advanced programmers, too — if I just need a quick and dirty PRNG to check something out, I use `rand()`.

Comment: @PeteBecker The correct message is "You cannot rely on rand() having good quality of randomness". Although beginners may rarely need to care about randomness of their programs, it is in my opinion important to learn this as soon as one learns about random numbers. If one merely learns of rand(), and not about its problems nor about its alternatives, they might never learn those in their path of becoming a software engineer. They may end up using what they've learned in places where rand() does not belong. It's OK to write rand() when one knows that it is good enough.

Comment: The generator I wrote was linear congruential, with carefully chosen parameters to maximize the period. It ran at higher precision, and the middle bits were masked and shifted to produce the result. I think it also cached 8 generated values, and randomly chose which one to return and replace.

Answer (score 2):

This is not supposed to replace the good answer, just an additional filler.

> What is the purpose of `static_cast<int>`?

It's very long and described here:

[`expr.static.cast`](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#1):

"*The result of the expression `static_­cast<T>(v)` is the result of converting the expression v to type T. If T is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type, the result is an lvalue; if T is an rvalue reference to object type, the result is an xvalue; otherwise, the result is a prvalue. The `static_­cast` operator shall not cast away constness.*"

More: https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast